# jQuery slider and simple menu not showing up in IE6 (CSS issue?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer-6

I have done a jQuery slider using EasySlider which is supposedly IE6 compatible and have made a simple menu bar below.

I'm having issues with them both working in IE6.

I've set up a JSFiddle with the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/PVS5B/1/

Would really appreciate it if someone with good CSS knowledge have a look at my CSS and can figure out why it's not working.

In IE6 the slider comes up, but the slides don't appear apart from the YouTube clip and the menu background shows, but no menu options (#controlslider).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use another jquery slider, for example nivoslider.

Answer (score 0):

IE was very young at that time, i guess only 6 years old :P when these awesome sliders came into being, so that's why IE cannot handle this, you cannot blame a child for this bug, children are innocent.

hope this helps.